# JQuery doesn't work when I load contents using AJAX

Tags: jquery, pinterest

I have a problem when I load page using AJAX.I have created a pinterest type arrangement using jquery.

But when I load it using Ajax it doesn't work.

I have searched for it and found bind() function.But how to use it with .css in JQuery.Results i found after searching weren't satisfactory.

Comment: Try to invoke functions you are called in ajax page after ajax request

Comment: Can i use bind jquery function?Please help

Comment: can you paste the code of your ajax cal?

Comment: posted the JQuery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your function like

```
   function indmoreclik(a,b)
   {
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
  document.getElementById("more").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

    var t1=0;
    var t2=0;
    var t3=0;

  for(j=1;j<=20;j++)
 {
  $('.div1:nth-child('+j+')').css({ top:''+t1+'px',left:'250px'});
  height=$('.div1:nth-child('+j+')').outerHeight(true);
  t1=t1+height;
  $('.div2:nth-child('+j+')').css({ top:''+t2+'px',left:'520px'});
  height=$('.div2:nth-child('+j+')').outerHeight(true);
  t2=t2+height;
 $('.div3:nth-child('+j+')').css({ top:''+t3+'px',left:'790px'});
 height=$('.div3:nth-child('+j+')').outerHeight(true);
 t3=t3+height;

  }
 }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","tap2.php?tun="+a+"&inc="+b,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Comment: call the functions you are using in document ready ,after ajax request completed